# Micronaut: How to include a property file to be readed using environment class

Tags: properties, micronaut, properties-file

I'm using micronaut.

I have a property file with some extra properties, the property file looks like this ("message.properties"):

```
my.key=a big message
my.key2=another message
other.key=another random message
...
```

message.properties file is included in the resources folder.

How can I load this file so I can get the value in the code searching for the key?

Something like:

```
String message = environment.getProperty("my.key2", String.class).orElse("Hello");
```

Thanks in advise